# SQL Group By / Count: Count Same Values Across Multiple Columns?

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, t-sql, count, group-by

I'm trying to figure out how to write a query that counts values across multiple columns, with the result table having a count in each column for every possible value of *any* column.

Example: Say I have *mytable*

```
Source data table:

P1  P2  P3
-----------
a   b   a
a   a   a
b   b   b
a   b   b
```

I want a query that counts a's and b's in each column, producing something like:

```
Desired query output:

     P1  P2  P3
   -------------
a |  3   1   2
b |  1   3   2
```

I know I can do this for a single column easily with a *group by*:

```sql
select P1, count(*) as mycounts
from mytable
group by P1
```

But is it possible to do this for *every* column?

I'm using SQL Server 2008 (T-SQL). Thanks in advance for any help!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Maybe something like this:

First some test data:

```
DECLARE @tbl TABLE(P1 VARCHAR,P2 VARCHAR,P3 VARCHAR)

INSERT INTO @tbl
SELECT 'a','b','a' UNION ALL
SELECT 'a','a','a' UNION ALL
SELECT 'b','b','b' UNION ALL
SELECT 'a','b','b'
```

Then a pivot like this:

```
SELECT
    *
FROM
(
    SELECT 'P1' AS P, P1 AS PValue,P1 AS test FROM @tbl
    UNION ALL
    SELECT 'P2',P2,P2 FROM @tbl
    UNION ALL
    SELECT 'P3',P3,P3 FROM @tbl
) AS p
PIVOT
(
    COUNT(PValue)
    FOR P IN ([P1],[P2],[P3])
) AS pvt
```

[Here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177410.aspx) is more information about pivot and unpivot

Comment: Thanks, Arion! This is beautiful! Now to study the syntax and learn the guts of these functions :D

Comment: You might consider accepting the answer then. Glad to help :) .. I added a like in the answer to the msdn page for pivots.

Comment: And now I've learned how to accept an answer. Oh, internet pedagogy, how I adore thee.

Answer (score 0):

Probably not the most efficient but this works.

```
    ;WITH data
AS
(
    SELECT 'a' AS p1, 'b' AS p2, 'a' AS p3
    UNION ALL
    SELECT 'a', 'a','a'
    UNION ALL
    SELECT 'b','b','b'
    UNION ALL
    SELECT 'a','b','b'
)
SELECT
    p_one.value AS header,
    p1,
    p2,
    p3
FROM (SELECT
          p1 AS value,
          count(*) AS p1
      FROM data d
      GROUP BY p1) p_one
left JOIN (SELECT
            p2 AS value,
            count(*) AS p2
            FROM data d
            GROUP BY p2) p_two
    ON p_two.value = p_one.value
left JOIN (SELECT
            p3 AS value,
            count(*) AS p3
            FROM data d
            GROUP BY p3) p_three
    ON p_two.value = p_three.value
```

Comment: The cte is good, but make the following query a pivot statement.

Comment: left join won't work here either. ie. if p1 only as "a"s then "b"s in p2 and p3 will be ignored.