# Group values from different columns and Count

Tags: mysql, sql, count, group-by

I have this table:

```
UNIQUE_ID | WINNER_ID | FINALIST_ID
________1 | ________1 | __________2
________2 | ________1 | __________3
________3 | ________3 | __________1
________4 | ________1 | __________2
```

And I need a list of all players (Winners and Finalists) and a COUNT of how many times they have got 1st or 2nd place.

In this case it would be:

```
PLAYER_ID | WINNER_TIMES | FINALIST_TIMES
________1 | ___________3 | _____________1
________2 | ___________0 | _____________2
________3 | ___________1 | _____________1
```

A similar question was already asked here ([LINK](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9185858/sql-group-by-count-count-same-values-across-multiple-columns)), but I didn't understand the answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
select  coalesce(winner_id, finalist_id) as PLAYER_ID
,       count(winner_id) as WINNER_TIMES
,       count(finalist_id) as FINALIST_TIMES
from    (
        select  winner_id
        ,       null as finalist_id
        from    YourTable
        union all
        select  null
        ,       finalist_id
        from    YourTable
        ) as SubQueryAlias
group by
        coalesce(winner_id, finalist_id)
```

[Live example at SQL Fiddle.](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/45922/2/0)

Comment: Thank you Andomar. I still need to learn more about having multiple selects.

Answer (score 0):

Try this ::

```
 Select 
    user_id as user, 
    winner_temp.count(1) as winning_count
    finalist_temp.count(1) as runner_up_count
    from
    user_table 
    left join 
    (Select winner_id, count(1) from table group by winner_id) as winner_temp on (user_table.user_id = winner_temp.winner_id)
    left join 
    (Select finalist_id, count(1) from table group by finalist_id) as finalist_temp on 
    (user_table.user_id = finalist_temp.finalist_id)
```