# Products comparision database schema

Tags: sql, database-design, database-schema, database-performance

We want to store comparison data between two or more products in our shopping web site.

I found the following link, but when we try that we had some performance issues

[SQL Group By / Count: Count Same Values Across Multiple Columns?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9185858/sql-group-by-count-count-same-values-across-multiple-columns)

How can we store our data? What should our table schema for comparison history data and how can I show the most compared products? What will be the query?

Answer (score 0):

The question is pretty broad and a little vague, my answer may be inclusive of considerations you've already made.

In order to do the comparison logic you need three things; the product, the ratings of that product and some method to logically group products for comparison. Granularity with proper indexes is usually best.

Here is an example of the tables/indexes I would create:

```
Create  Table Product (ProductID Int, ProductName Varchar(256), etc)
Create  Table Groups (GroupID Int, GroupName Varchar(256), etc)
Create  Table ProductGroup (ProductID Int, GroupID Int)
Create  Table RatingType (RatingID Int, RatingName Varchar(64))
Create  Table ProductRatings (ProductID Int, RatingID Int, RatingValue Varchar(32))

Create  Clustered Index ix_Product_pID On Product (ProductID)
Create  Nonclustered Index ix_Product_pID_pName On Product (ProductID, ProductName)
Create  Clustered Index ix_Groups_gID On Groups (GroupID)
Create  Nonclustered Index ix_ProductGroup_gID_pID On ProductGroup (GroupID, ProductID)
Create  Clustered Index ix_RatingType_rID On RatingType (RatingID)
Create  Nonclustered Index ix_ProductRatings_pID_rID On ProductRatings (ProductID, RatingID)
```

Putting Clustered Indexes on Product, Group and RatingType make sense as their ID columns will be their identity columns so you don't have to worry about the physical ordering since they will be sequential. ProductGroup and ProductRatings on the other hand can receive any records in any order at anytime so putting clustered indexes on them would slow down inserts and cause faster fragmentation.

To perform the logic done in the query in the linked example you would do something like this:

```
Create  Proc GetProductComparisonRatings (@productID Int, @ratingID Int)
As

Declare @columns Nvarchar(Max), 
        @SQL Nvarchar(Max);

;With   DistinctCols As
(
        Select  Distinct p.productName
        From    ProductGroup pg1
        Join    ProductGroup pg2
                On  pg1.groupID = pg2.groupID
        Join    Product p
                On  pg2.productID = p.productID
        Where   pg1.productID = @productID      
)
Select  @columns = Coalesce(@columns + ',','') + '[' + productName + ']'
From    DistinctCols
Order   By  Case
            When    p.productID = @productID Then 0
            Else    1
            End;        -- This will put your product that was the basis of the comparison as the leftmost column

Select  @SQL = ';With   baseRecords As
                (
                        Select  pg2.productID, 
                                pr.ratingValue, 
                                Count(1) As cnt
                        From    ProductGroup pg1
                        Join    ProductGroup pg2
                                On  pg1.groupID = pg2.groupID
                        Join    ProductRatings pr
                                On  pg2.productID = pr.productID
                                And pr.ratingID = ' + @ratingID + '
                        Where   pg1.productID = ' + @productID + '
                        Group   By  pg2.productID, 
                                    pr.ratingValue;
                )
                Select  ratingValue, ' + @columns + '
                From    baseRecords br
                Join    product p
                        On  br.productID = p.productID
                Pivot   (Sum(cnt) For p.productName In (' + @columns + ')) pivot';

Exec    sp_executeSQL @SQL;
```

This takes it a step farther and limits the ratings comparison to a specific ratingType; some examples could be (durability, size, overall). If you only have one ratingType it will still work fine. You can edit or change it however you want.

Comment: This is not i meant. There must be a comparisions table that customer's comparisions can be saved. And then we want to list the most compared products or in a product information form we want to show 'this product is the most compared with another product'.

Comment: Can you please provide the schema of the proposed comparisons table? There are many ways you could do it and it will be more productive to work within your conception thus far; if there are problems with it then I can make suggestions at that point.